# Asyncio long running tasks

Tags: python-asyncio

For example have standart scenario for long running task in web application.
For example there is some Http application (with Asyncio of course). 
Client comes to this application and makes some request, for exmaple get infomation for another sites. Server should create `task` and return task's id to client. After some time client make request with task's id to determine task's status.

I thought to use regular dict to store tasks, but when task was finished (fail or success) I should store its result. 
And I think to use this solution:

1. Get request - create task (asyncio.create_task).
2. Create task's id (uuid) put it to dict
3. when task is finished store its result to Redis
4. when user requests look for task in dict first and is there is no task look in redis for getting task's status.

Like Celery isn't?
Is this good way or not?

Comment: Why not just use celery?

Comment: celery is not for asycnio

Comment: So? If you're running the task in the background and clients will make new requests to check on the status of a task, why does the task need to run as part of the same event loop as your web application?

Comment: call task.delay() for put task in Celery is not async. Loop will be locked when call blocking functions.